# Android, java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ....R$layout.e

Tags: android

App with several modules.
'prestaAdmin' include 'Controls' and 'eShop', 'eshop' include 'Licensing'.
settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':Controls', ':Licensing', ':eShop'
```

In build.gradle(module eshop) put

```
dependencies{
compile project(':Licensing')}
```

In build.gradle(module app) put

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
dependencies{
compile project(':Controls')
compile project(':eShop')}
```

AndroidManifest of eshop:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="appmobile.biz.eshop"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Start" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Main" android:label="@string/main_title" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Catalog" android:label="@string/catalog_list_title" android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:resource="@xml/catalog_searchable" android:name="android.app.searchable"></meta-data>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.PageView" ></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.EditField" ></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.ViewField" ></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Orders"></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.CategorySelector" android:label="@string/select_category"></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Statistics" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.StatViewed"></activity>
        <activity android:name="appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.StatPurchased"></activity>
    </application>
```

AndroidManifest of app

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="appmobile.biz.prestaadmin"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="1.1">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Start.java:

```
public class Start extends Activity
{

    private TextView               krikTV;


public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        super.setContentView( R.layout.krikstartoncreate);



        krikTV = ( (TextView) super.findViewById( R.id.krikTV ) );
        krikTV.setText("krikstartoncreate text");
```

krikstartoncreate layout(in eShop/res/layout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/krikTV" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: appmobile.biz.eshop.R$layout.e
                                                     at appmobile.biz.eshop.ui.Start.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If i debug,see this:

```
krikTV = No such instance field: 'krikTV'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have one project working as a library that declares some id in a given XML file, then your main project redefines that XML, the original id is gone, but you won't see the error until run time.

In my case, a partner deleted and committed the XML from the project, then added it back in the library project. Subclipse didn't seems to notice that because I was up to date, but the XML was there on the main project.

in short.
 **Two layout files with the same name.**

change either of those file name :)

Comment: I have just one layout file krikstartoncreate in eShop/res/layout.
In app i don't have this layout.

Comment: work for me.I am having the same layout file in project as well as in module.